# How to post sha512 encrypted data

Tags: php, post, hash, checksum, sha512

I need help for my PHP script. I need to post certain fields like invoiceid, firstname, email, etc in encrypted way. The formula for the checksum is

```
sha512 (key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5||||||<SALT>)
```

I need to post the above variables via sha512. I am unable to do this. Please help with this. Im a learner and I am not good at PHP.

Here is the code. Im still getting checksum error.

```
<?php
function xxx_config() {

    $configarray = array(
     "FriendlyName" => array("Type" => "System", "Value"=>"XXX"),
     "alias" => array("FriendlyName" => "Merchant ID", "Type" => "text", "Size" => "20", ),
     "salt" => array("FriendlyName" => "SALT", "Type" => "text", "Size" => "20",),
     "mode" => array("FriendlyName" => "MODE", "Type" => "text", "Description" => "TEST or LIVE", ),

    );
    return $configarray;
}

function xxx_link($params) {


    # Gateway Specific Variables
    $key = $params['alias'];
    $gatewaymode = $params['mode'];
    $salt = $params['salt'];


    # Invoice Variables
    $txnid = $params['invoiceid'];
    $productinfo = $params["description"];
    $amount = $params['amount']; # Format: ##.##
    $currency = $params['currency']; # Currency Code

    # Client Variables
    $firstname = $params['clientdetails']['firstname'];
    $lastname = $params['clientdetails']['lastname'];
    $email = $params['clientdetails']['email'];
    $address1 = $params['clientdetails']['address1'];
    $address2 = $params['clientdetails']['address2'];
    $city = $params['clientdetails']['city'];
    $state = $params['clientdetails']['state'];
    $postcode = $params['clientdetails']['postcode'];
    $country = $params['clientdetails']['country'];
    $phone = $params['clientdetails']['phonenumber'];

    # System Variables
    $companyname = 'XXX';
    $systemurl = $params['systemurl'];
    $currency = $params['currency'];

        # Enter your code submit to the gateway...

$hashdata = ($key."|".$txnid."|".$amount."|".$productinfo."|".$firstname."|".$email."|"."|"."|"."|"."|"."|".$salt);

   $hash = hash("sha512", $hashdata);

$code = '<form method="post" action="https://secure.xxx.xxx" name="frmTransaction" id="frmTransaction" onSubmit="return validate()">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="'.$key.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="'.$gatewaymode.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value="'.$productinfo.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="'.$txnid.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="salt" value="'.$salt.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="'.$firstname.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="address" value="'.$address1.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="'.$city.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="'.$state.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="'.$country.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="postal_code" value="'.$postcode.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="ship_name" value="'.$firstname.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="ship_address" value="'.$address1.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="ship_city" value="'.$city.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="ship_state" value="'.$state.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="ship_country" value="'.$country.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="ship_postal_code" value="'.$postcode.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="ship_phone" value="'.$phone.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="'.$email.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="phone" value="'.$phone.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$amount.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="surl" value="https://xxx.xx/xxxx.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="furl" value="https://xxx.xx/xxx.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="Hash" value="'.$hash.'"/>
<input type="submit" value="Pay Now" />
</form>';

return $code;

}
?>
```

Comment: Are the `|`s supposed to be literal `|` characters? So you need to concatenate your variables with `|` and a salt and put the resulting string through sha512? Can't be that hard, what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: Also, SHA512 !== "encryption". It's a *hash*!

Comment: Tx for your suggestion and correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [hash](http://php.net/hash)() function is what you are looking for. To create an sha512 hash call it as follows:

```
hash('sha512', "the value to hash");
```

to see what Hash-Algorithms else you could use take a look at the [hash_algos](http://php.net/hash_algos)() function

Comment: Your formula is correct, but as per their formula all the values like txnid, name etc, should be encrypted or hashed with sha512 algorithm, i.e., sha512(values) but the above formula does not do that. Please help with another method.

Comment: do you want to concatenate every value (txnid) with `|` and then hash it all together or do you want to hash every single value and then concatenate it?

Comment: Every value with | and then hash it. in the above formula if fields are empty then it should carry one PIP for each. Like if I dont have udf in above formula then i have replace that with one pipe i.e., total 11 pipes should come.

Comment: @user1570503, me too have same issue... same formula... if you got final answer, help me too